# Fatou's Lemma: How to apply it for $E[|X|] \leq \liminf_n E[|X_n|]$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, expectation, limsup-and-liminf

Let $X_n$ for $n \geq 0$ be a sequence of random variables with $\sup_n E[X_n^+]  < \infty$ and $X_n \overset{P-a.s.}{\rightarrow} X$.

We have shown that $$E[X_0] \leq E[X_n ] =E[X_n^+]-E[X_n^-]< \infty$$

and that

$$E[X_n^-] \leq E[X_n^+] - E[X_0] < \infty.$$

Now we conclude

1. $\sup_n E[|X_n|] < \infty$
2. $E[|X|] \leq \liminf_n E[|X_n|] < \infty$ using Fatou's Lemma

Can you help me providing some more Details for These two conclusions?

1. $\sup_n E[|X_n|] = \sup_n E[\max(X_n^+, X_n^-)]< \infty$, since the above inequalities are Independent of $n$, so $E[X_n^+]$ and $E[X_n^-]$ are uniformly bounded?
2. Here I have no idea what the supremum has to do with $\liminf_n$, so we would Need to write $E[|X|] \leq \dotsc \leq E[\liminf_n |X_n|] \leq \liminf_n E[|X_n|] < \infty$.

You see, I Need some Details here how to convert $|X|$ to $X_n^+$, $X_n^-$.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The first inequality after "we have shown" is not true in general. Do you have other hypothesis you did not mention? For 1.: we have $\sup_nE[X_n^-]\leqslant \sup_nE[X_n^-]-E[X_0]$ hence $\sup_nE|X_n|\leqslant 2\sup_nE[X_n^+]-E[X_0]$.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion: yes we have other assumptions I did not mention because I thought that only what happens at 1. and 2. is relevant, given the two derivations above. We have the assumption that $X_n$ is a submartingale, which implies the inequality $E[X_0] \leq E[X_n]$. Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbb E[X_0]\leqslant \mathbb E[X_n]$ for each $n$, we have 
$$\sup_n\mathbb E[X_n^-]\leqslant \sup_n\mathbb E[X_n^+]-\mathbb E[X_0]$$
and the right hand side is finite by assumption.

For 2., we apply Fatou's lemma to the non-negative sequence $\left(\left|X_n\right|\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ (which converges almost everywhere to $\left|X\right|$).